# How to load values from properties using Configuration class and use it in test classes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking, integration-testing

Below is my @Configuration class that loads the properties from application.yml:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "products")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sale.clearance")
    public Map<String,String> products() { return new HashMap<>() ;
}
```

I am writing a Junit test class. Below is the snippet of the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class,MockitoExtension.class})
@SpringBootTest
@ActivePRofiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyConfiguration.class)
public class MyControllerTest {
    @Resource(name = "products")
    public Map<String,String> products;

    @Mock
    SomeService someService;
    ...
    ...
}
```

The products map is still showing as null.

I don't want to mock the object for products map. Instead I want to use a similar configuration class to load from the yml file. How can I achieve it? Should I write a new test configuration class?

Comment: `map is still showing as null` - that means the spring is not even trying to inject it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `application—test.yml`，You can check `activeProfile`usage

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).